# How can I use groupBy to create a map whose values are averages of BigDecimal fields?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have the following class:

```
final public class Person {

 private final String name;
 private final String state;
 private final BigDecimal salary;

 public Person(String name, String state, BigDecimal salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
    this.salary = salary;
 }

 //getters omitted for brevity...
}
```

I want to create a map which lists the average of salaries by state. How can I do so using Java8 streams? I tried to use downstream collectors on the groupBy but wasn't able to do so in an elegant way.

I did the following which works but is pretty hideous looking:

```
Stream.of(p1,p2,p3,p4).collect(groupingBy(Person::getState, mapping(d -> d.getSalary(), toList())))
.forEach((state,wageList) -> {
        System.out.print(state+"-> ");
        final BigDecimal[] wagesArray = wageList.stream()
                .map(bd -> new BigDecimal[]{bd, BigDecimal.ONE})
                .reduce((a, b) -> new BigDecimal[]{a[0].add(b[0]), a[1].add(BigDecimal.ONE)})
                .get();
        System.out.println(wagesArray[0].divide(wagesArray[1])
                                        .setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
    });
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need to retain BigDecimal precision, or can the result be a double?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. With a double, this is easy because I can just use the averagingDouble function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete example using only BigDecimal arithmetics, and showing how to implement a custom collector

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public final class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String state;
    private final BigDecimal salary;

    public Person(String name, String state, BigDecimal salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person("John", "NY", new BigDecimal("2000"));
        Person p2 = new Person("Jack", "NY", new BigDecimal("3000"));
        Person p3 = new Person("Jane", "GA", new BigDecimal("1500"));
        Person p4 = new Person("Jackie", "GA", new BigDecimal("2500"));

        Map<String, BigDecimal> result =
            Stream.of(p1, p2, p3, p4).collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getState,
                                      Collectors.mapping(Person::getSalary,
                                                         new AveragingCollector())));
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

    }

    private static class AveragingCollector implements Collector<BigDecimal, IntermediateResult, BigDecimal> {
        @Override
        public Supplier<IntermediateResult> supplier() {
            return IntermediateResult::new;
        }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<IntermediateResult, BigDecimal> accumulator() {
            return IntermediateResult::add;
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<IntermediateResult> combiner() {
            return IntermediateResult::combine;
        }

        @Override
        public Function<IntermediateResult, BigDecimal> finisher() {
            return IntermediateResult::finish
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
    }

    private static class IntermediateResult {
        private int count = 0;
        private BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        IntermediateResult() {
        }

        void add(BigDecimal value) {
            this.sum = this.sum.add(value);
            this.count++;
        }

        IntermediateResult combine(IntermediateResult r) {
            this.sum = this.sum.add(r.sum);
            this.count += r.count;
            return this;
        }

        BigDecimal finish() {
            return sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(count), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        }
    }
}
```

If you accept to transform your BigDecimal values to double (which, for an average of salaries, is perfectly acceptable, IMHO), you can just use

```
Map<String, Double> result2 =
            Stream.of(p1, p2, p3, p4).collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getState,
                                      Collectors.mapping(Person::getSalary,
                                                         Collectors.averagingDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue))));
```

Comment: Is it worth adding a mapping collector just to use a method reference?

Comment: No, not really. I just used the same template as in the first example.

Comment: There is no need for the `AveragingCollector` class, you can simply use `Collector.of(IntermediateResult::new, IntermediateResult::add, IntermediateResult::combine, IntermediateResult::finish)` to get an equivalent `Collector<BigDecimal, IntermediateResult, BigDecimal>` instance. Besides that, I recommend using `long` for the `count`, there is no need for restricting this code to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` stream elements…  Oh, and “aruthmetics” → “arithmetics”.

Comment: @Holger thanks. I *knew* I had seen this factory method somewhere, but was looking for it in the Collectors class.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** This is not the best solution. Read below (from the edit on) for a better approach.

You could use [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) to accumulate salaries on a per-state basis into an `ArrayList`, then use the finisher function to calculate the average for every state:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> salariesByState = Stream.of(p1, p2, p3, p4).collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getState,
        Collectors.mapping(Person::getSalary,
            Collector.<BigDecimal, List<BigDecimal>, BigDecimal>of(
                ArrayList::new, // create accumulator
                List::add,      // add to accumulator
                (l1, l2) -> {   // combine two partial accumulators
                    l1.addAll(l2);
                    return l1;
                },
                l -> l.stream() // finish with a reduction that returns average
                    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
                    .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(l.size()))))));
```

This approach doesn't lose precision, as every operation to calculate the average per state is performed on a `BigDecimal` instance.

**EDIT:** As @Holger indicates in his comment, this is not the best way to solve the problem, as using an `ArrayList` to store all the `BigDecimal` instances is not needed at all to calculate the average. Instead, using a `BigDecimal` to accumulate the partial sum and a `long` to accumulate the count will suffice (this is the approach followed by @JB Nizet in his answer, here I'm modifying a few minor details).

Here's a modified version that takes these considerations into account:

```
private static class Acc {
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    long count = 0;

    void add(BigDecimal v) {
        sum = sum.add(v);
        count++;
    }

    Acc merge(Acc acc) {
        sum = sum.add(acc.sum);
        count += acc.count;
        return this;
    }

    BigDecimal avg() {
        return sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

`Acc` is the class used to accumulate partial results (both the partial sum and count).

Now, we can use `Collector.of` with this class:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> salariesByState = Stream.of(p1, p2, p3, p4).collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getState,
        Collectors.mapping(Person::getSalary,
            Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, Acc::avg))));
```

Or even better, we can declare a helper method with the `Acc` class being a local class:

```
public static Collector<BigDecimal, ?, BigDecimal> averagingBigDecimal() {
    class Acc { // local class, lives only inside this method :P
        BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        long count = 0;

        void add(BigDecimal value) {
            sum = sum.add(value);
            count++;
        }

        Acc merge(Acc acc) {
            sum = sum.add(acc.sum);
            count += acc.count;
            return this;
        }

        BigDecimal avg() {
            return sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(count));
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, Acc::avg);
}
```

This method can now be used as follows:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> salariesByState = Stream.of(p1, p2, p3, p4).collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getState,
        Collectors.mapping(Person::getSalary, averagingBigDecimal())));
```

Comment: I’m not sure whether this is simpler than the OP’s original approach, but it’s less efficient, for sure.

Comment: @Holger you are right, I'm using an ArrayList to accumulate all the elements, but I don't need this. Summing in one BigDecimal and counting with a long is enough, there's no need for an intermediate data structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you need `BigDecimal` precision, and you don't mind an extra iteration, you can do this:

```
static Map<String, BigDecimal> averageByState(List<Person> persons) {
    // collect sums
    Map<String, BigDecimal> sumByState = persons.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(
                    Person::getState,
                    HashMap::new,
                    mapping(Person::getSalary, reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));

    // collect counts
    Map<String, Long> countByState = persons.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Person::getState, counting()));

    // merge
    sumByState.replaceAll((state, sum) -> sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(countByState.get(state))));
    return sumByState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it. Although I still believe there may be other better ways of doing it.

```
Map<String, Double> collect = Arrays.asList(p, p1, p2, p3, p4)
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(k -> k.getState(), mapping(v -> v.salary, toList())))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(toMap(k -> k.getKey(), v -> v.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble()));
```

Comment: If you're not going for precision, you can just do `Stream.of(p1,p2,p3,p4).collect(groupingBy(Person::getState, averagingDouble(p -> p.getSalary().doubleValue())))`